# Kaazing Topic Subscription

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic, kaazing

Using kaazing jms demo with AMQP 1.0 AND ActiveMQ

```
https://demo.kaazing.com/demo/jms/javascript/jms-javascript.html
```

Register/Subscribe to new Queue and process it for application server and send message back to client[kaazing] from application server.However, client subscribed to same queue did not received any message, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to use two browsers clients: a publisher and a subscriber. I just tested it, and it works fine on the URL you provided above.

A while back I published a [6-minute screencast](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/16/quick-start-with-the-kaazing-websocket-gateway-in-less-than-6-minutes/) of the steps. You can see the messages flying back-and-forth at around 3:30.